# End of file reading in c

Tags: c

My program is reading the last line of data from an infile twice. When I execute the program, the last line of data is being printed twice. Please Help me! Here is the code,

```
while ( !feof ( in ) ) {
//fread();
}
```

I hope this happens because of `feof` functionality.

I don't want to use `fgets` or `getline`. Is there is any other way? Please direct me.

Thanks to all who responded me! I got the solution for this! I did with `fgetc` and `unfgetc` in side the `do` loop.

Here is the code:

```
int ch;
ch=fgetc(fp);
do
{
ungetc(ch,fp);
//fread();

ch=fgetc(fp);
} while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && ch != '\n' );
```

Comment: what function are you using to read from the file?

Comment: can you add more lines from your code ?

Comment: hi vivek am using fread to read the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a do... while loop to use `feof()` properly in c.

```
if (!feof()) // in case the file is zero length.
{
  do
  {
       //whatever....          
  } while(!feof())
}
```

Comment: I tried using 'do' and it still reads last block of data twice

Answer (score 1):

Try this! Use `fscanf` for input operations.

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%s", in) != EOF) {
//your code
}
```